# Value of the sum of reciprocals of the sum of primes

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to find whether the following series converges or diverges:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^nP_i}$$

I've evaluated it using a Raspberry Pi 3 up to x = 200000 and got a 2.3MB text file containing a fraction $\approx$ 1.0234756204301129964.

Comment: According to Wolfram, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} P_i \sim \frac{1}{2}n^2\log n$, so your series converges. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, this is equivalent to the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) $p_n \sim n \ln n \implies \sum_{n < x} p_n \sim \int_1^x  t \ln(t) dt = \frac{x^2}{2}\ln x - \int_1^x \frac{t^2}{2} \frac{1}{t}dt \sim \frac{x^2}{2}\ln x$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews do you know of any specific reading material that could help me understand this? Now I'm just stuck with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n^2 \log n}$

Comment: @Brian Ivan's answer is cleaner, but if you know that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, you know that $\sum\frac{2}{n^2\log n}$ converges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $P_i>i$, hence ${\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_i}>{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i}$, hence ${1\over\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_i}<{1\over\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i}$, hence your sum is less than $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{1\over\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n(n+1)/2}=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left({1\over n}-{1\over n+1}\right)=2$. So it converges, after all.

With some calculus, this becomes obvious even faster.